# Passing an NSMutable Array Between Classes

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, pass-by-reference

I have a question I hope someone can answer. I am new to Objective C, and while most of it poses me little trouble, it has become evident I don't understand passing NSMutableArrays between classes properly. Here is the relevant code:

this is the class I want to catch the NSMutableArray

```
#import "CanBee.h"
#import "Rat.h"
@implementation CanBee
-(id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        if([[self parent] respondsToSelector:@selector(getRatsArray)] == YES)
        {
            ratsArray = (NSMutableArray *) [[self parent] performSelector:@selector(getRatsArray)];
        }
        [self scheduleUpdate];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= ratsArray.count; i++) {
        NSLog(@"in rats array loop in canBee: %i",i);
        Rat * rat = [ratsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if (abs(self.position.x - rat.position.x) < 10 && abs(self.position.y - rat.position.y) < 10) {
            [[self parent] removeChild: rat cleanup:TRUE]; //<-- this line is probably not correct, but not relevant to my question anyway, don't worry about it for this post
        }
    }
}

@end
```

this is from the init function from the gameLayer class, my main controller class for my game

```
    ratsArray = [NSMutableArray alloc];

    Rat * rat = [Rat spriteWithFile:@"rat.png"];
    [rat setPosition:ccp((4 * 53) - 25,100)];
    [rat setScale:.75];
    [self addChild:rat z:6];

    [ratsArray addObject:rat];
```

and this is the getter function in the same controller class

```
-(NSMutableArray *) getRatsArray {
    return ratsArray;
}
```

I should mention that ratsArray is a global variable in the controller class and separately, also in the catcher "CanBee" class.

I should also mention I really want to not pass a copy of the array, but instead to pass a pointer, or reference, so that my catching class can interact with the original array and its contained objects.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: ratsArray = [NSMutableArray alloc]; <--- You have to call init or initWith… on objects you send alloc to. Otherwise they may not be fully initialized and weird things are bound to happen!

Comment: thank you, I noticed this too and changed it to [... new]; :)

Answer (score 2):

I would just add an alternative implementation of init that takes ratsArray as a parameter, and be sure to give the method a meaningful name.  This way you don't need the line of code to get it from the controller.  It would look something like this:

```
#import "CanBee.h"
#import "Rat.h"
@implementation CanBee
-(id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
    }
    return self;
}

-(id) initWithRatsArray:(NSMutableArray *)ratsArray 
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        ratsArray = ratsArray;
        //don't forget about proper memory management here
        [ratsArray retain]
        [self scheduleUpdate];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then, when you instantiate the CanBee class, pass ratsArray as a parameter, like:

```
CanBee *aCanBee = [[CanBee alloc] initWithRatsArray:ratsArray];
```

Comment: `init:` is a horrible name for a method because there is no indication as to what it expects. `initWithRatsArray:` would be a much better name.

Comment: Good point, just updated my answer with your suggestion, thanks

Comment: Thank you so much! this helped a lot, now my game is working great! It seems strange there isn't a good way to just pass NSMutableArrays after the initialization, but I don't mind this work around since it works great in this instance. I hope it will always work! I should mention that this tip solved my problem exactly to all the specifications I wanted.